# Getting a specific element in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I've been asked to make a website for an organisation and they want me to let users register with a (already set) user ID, which is stored in a local database, and grab the rest from an external XML API provided by the 'master' organization. Since we are only using the user CID and password, I've already set `$_SESSION['cid']`, but my problem is getting the user information from the XML file. So far I've tried (to no avail):

```
$cid= $_SESSION['cid'];
//Get user information
if($xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.vateud.net/members/FRA.xml')){
  $count = count($xml -> member);
  foreach($xml->member as $member){
    if($member->cid == $cid){
      //Success
    } else {
      //Get ID error
      die;
    }
  }
} else {
  //XML load error
  die;
}
```

The XML file: http://api.vateud.net/members/FRA.xml

If you look at the XML file, how would I go about getting the user information inside the respective `<member>` tag for that specific user. In simple words (pseudocode): how would I get the `firstname` and `lastname` values WHERE `cid` = `$_SESSION['cid']`?

Comment: Umm `$member->firstname` and `$member->lastname`!?

Comment: ^^ that must have been pretty obvious, I guess your value is not matching, where is `session_start()`? Have you checked `$_SESSION['cid']` contains a value?

Comment: All the session variables are already declared above the code. I've just tried to debug it, it does work, BUT: it only gets the first few elements... There is a user near the bottom that I'm testing for and it just returns the custom error I set in `//Get ID error`. So it seems that SimpleXML doesn't want to load larger files?

Comment: Its exiting after the first loop `die;`, why are you using die at all?

Comment: I'm using `die;` because I've been using custom HTML error messages with custom error codes, so the usage of `die;` in the last `if` statement stops the rest of the code from being executed... If it did get executed, then all the variables on the dashboard would be undefined.

Comment: Also just tested removing `die;`, it just returns 232 _custom errors_ (the count of all members).

Comment: I've added an answer, which fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exiting after the first loop, I tweaked the script to pull out the item into an array.

```
<?php
session_start();

try {
    if (empty($_SESSION['cid'])) {
        throw new \Exception('Session cid not defined or empty');
    }

    $result = [];
    if ($xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.vateud.net/members/FRA.xml')) {
        foreach ($xml->member as $member) {
            if ($member->cid == $_SESSION['cid']) {
                $result = (array) $member;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Could not load XML');
    }

    // do somthing with result
    print_r($result);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // store in a variable if you wish
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [active] => true
    [cid] => 800000
    [country] => FR
    [firstname] => Foobar
    [humanized-atc-rating] => C3
    [humanized-pilot-rating] => P0
    [lastname] => Baz
    [pilot-rating] => 0
    [rating] => 7
    [reg-date] => 2001-01-01 12:00:00
    [subdivision] => FRA
)
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me 36 hours of pain and suffering.